# how to load XML data into data set using Delphi,without using third party components?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

i want to load XML data(around 25000+ records) into data set (TQuery, TStored Proc) without using third party components. i am using Delphi 5, so i do not have TClientDataSet.

Comment: You don't need TClientDataSet. Load the XML into a TXMLDocument, iterate through it, and write what you need out to your dataset.

Comment: @KenWhite Delphi 5 does not have TXMLDocument. That was introduced in Delphi 6.

Comment: @abhayk In order to achieve what you want without any third party component this means that you will hve to write your own XML parser which is not so easy. Anyway you might want to check oif you could find some older version of OmniXML written by Primoz Gabrielcic. If my memory serves me corectly he wrote it the time when many people still used Delphi 6 so it is Quite possible that it is compatible with delphi 5. But do note that OmniXML loads entire XML into memory and could therefore consume large amounts of memory in case if your XML's are as big as you are suggesting.

Comment: If you don't want to use a third party component, the only alternative, other than writing your own parser, is to import the MSXML COM objects yourself : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @SilverWarior: Then the OP has to either use a third-party library, write his/her own parser, or import MSXML. As the requirements are "without using third party components", that would rule out at least the first option (and depending on the OP's point of view, possibly the third).

Comment: As a third alternative for really old projects (as old as Delphi 5!), if upgrading is not an option, converting the project to Lazarus would give you free access to a lot of modern language tools, including `TXMLDocument`.

Comment: @J...: I'm pretty sure Lazarus would be considered a "third party" product. If the OP can't use any third party XML parser, I'd think a conversion to an entirely different third party IDE/language would also be unacceptable.

Comment: @KenWhite It's a little different - a third party component introduces new dependencies.  Changing development environment is a one-time change but it does not have the issues of reliance on third-party code.  If anything, switching to Lazarus over Delphi 5, I would think, is a positive move to shed some technical debt.

Comment: You have TClientDataSet in Delphi 5. (You need to distribute midas.dll with your application.)

Comment: i am using this solution <<http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26882>>

now i got other problem.. i got a COM DLL which uses MSXML.dll when i register COM DLL i am getting error "Type library exporter cannot load type 'MSXML.IXMLDOMDocument' (error: System.IO.FileNotFoundExc
eption: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MSXML, Version=2.0.0.0"

Comment: @abhayk Don't ask new questions in comments. Write a new, **clear** question (with code, errors, etc)